# Should I blur the cached snapshot of my app?

Tags: encryption, ios, data-leakage, caching

I recently ran a security scan on one of my iOS apps that suggested I modify my apps display as it enters the background so that the screenshot stored in the cache does not expose any sensitive data. I'm currently using apple's data protection library to encrypt all my apps data including the cached screenshot whenever the phone is locked using the user's pin. Is there any reason to modify the display under these circumstances?

*Edit:  Additional information*

- The screenshot is currently used to hide the apps small reload time so I'd like to keep it if it's not necessary to blur it out or remove it.
- This is an internal enterprise app that can only be used on devices with 8 digit device pins.
- We display data from the phones native calendar that may contain sensitive information

Comment: Does you app have it's own PIN? Or do you rely on the iOS lock screen?

Comment: Do you actually display sensitive information in the app? Then blurring or putting a default view in front would be useful.

Comment: @paj28 I rely on the iOS lock screen but this is an internal enterprise app that will be running alongside security software that enforces all our users create an eight digit device pin.

Comment: I think blurring is unnecessary. You need it when an app has its own PIN, but if the whole device is locked, you can't see the screenshot, so you're safe.

Comment: @SmokeDispenser Yes we take the users native calendar data which can contain sensitive information. Although if the attacker has access to the unlocked phone they could take this from the calendar easily enough.

Comment: Can I ask what software you used for the security scan?

Comment: @MarkKoek IBM AppScan
https://www.ibm.com/marketplace/cloud/application-security-on-cloud/us/en-us#product-header

Comment: @paj28 Is the snapshot being accessed by malware whilst the device is unlocked/unencrypted not a potential threat?

Comment: @Deco - no. If malware can do that, it can just nick the data directly.

Comment: @paj28 Feel free to put your 2nd comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.